# How to differentiate a call made to AWS services is by IAM user of by Cloud Formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am Filtering an cloud trail to identify events on security groups or on NACL's and cloud watch is giving me alerts. now i want to sort the calls made  by an IAM user and calls made by cloud formation scripts.

Is it possible? please help.

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you filtering? Show your CLI command.

Comment: i was doing it on console only.. followed document from AWS website.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer for this..
If we check the logs carefully we get multiple parameters out of which we can go for "sourceIPAddress". if event is because of cloud formation this IP address will get logged as ""cloudformation.amazonaws.com".
Just apply filter on source IP address and its done.

Its working properly.

Thanks